# Combine Reducers without their functional keys

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have been working on a React / Redux Application, where now the reducer for single feature has become big enough for the thought of dividing the reducer further.

So I was thinking is there a way to divide the reducer into two different reducers and combining them without adding keys of their functional names.

For Ex:

```
const nowShowing = function(state = {}, action){

     switch(action.type){
          case types.NS_MOVIES:
              return Object.assign({}, state, { nowShowingMovies: action.data })

}

const comingSoon = function(state = {}, action){

     switch(action.type){
          case types.CS_MOVIES:
              return Object.assign({}, state, { comingSoonMovies: action.data })

}
```

I am looking to check if its possible to combine these reducers

```
const movies = combineReducers({
    nowShowing,
    comingSoon
})
```

in such a way that i can access them in the following manner

```
mapStateToProps(state){
    nowShowing: state.movies.nowShowing,
    comingSoon: state.movies.comingSoon
}
```

The reason i am looking for a solution like this is because, it will allow my entire application to work as earlier, but the nowShowing & comingSoon reducer become separate and my code becomes more modular.

I did try returning an object instead of combining the reducer using the combineReducers function. But that causes the entire state of the reducer to reset when there is a change in value as it recreates the object.

I think this kind of solution is not possible or it should not be attempted. But I would to understand more why, as I do agree that this points to more over architectural flaw in constructing the reducers in the first place.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can absolutely do this, just architect your state tree out.

Comment: @ajmajmajma - this is just an example, my reducer contains about 20 cases each

Comment: Same still applies, you can shape the state and reducers however you want really. In the case of you have a more complicated state, your life will be much easier if you take a bit and architect the state our in an elegant way. It is really easy to fall into the pattern of "patching" onto it as you grow your application (that will make scenarios like these quite a bit harder).

Comment: @ajmajmajma - you are right, but i still tend to think that there has to be a better way to divide your reducers internally rather than changing the entire application architecture.
If that happens only that way when the application grows larger, the access to state values for the reducer remains the same, although internally it might on different reducers. I think Abstraction of this sense would really help. Although that is what i think, and i maybe wrong